# How do I solve this issue? I get this error while building an android project with gradle

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

Could not find property 'UniqueFirebaseRootUrl' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@3910186.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error, you need to add a value for UniqueFirebaseUrl in your gradle.properties file. You should create a file and add a line that looks like this: UniqueFirebaseRootUrl = "https://shoppinglistplspls.firebaseio.com/"

source: https://github.com/udacity/ShoppingListPlusPlus/issues/8